# Play Console Not Showing Full Stack Trace

Tags: java, android, google-play, stack-trace

I can't find the part of the stack trace in the Google Play Console that actually deals with my app's code, specifically.  All I get is the system stuff, without showing where in my code that is causing the error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2884)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1565)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2879)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android is completely open source. If you look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) for `ActivityThread` you can see that `handleReceiver()` is called when a Broadcast is received by your app.

If you read [the documentation for Broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) you can see that the Broadcast comes in from the Android OS, and goes to a class declared in your manifest. In the example given on that page, it looks like if your manifest looks like:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
```

Then you need a class like

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

I would guess from the stack trace you are declaring a broadcast receiver in your manifest that your APK doesn't have in it. Either you forgot to write the code, got the classname wrong, or something like proguard is incorrectly stripping it out (less likely).